# Trim all but last character in an element using CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Using pure CSS, would it be possible to trim all but the last character of text from within an element? Possibly with `content:()`?

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="current">Slide 1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Slide 2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Slide 3</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">Slide 4</a></li>
```

I need it to be

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="current">1</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">2</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">3</a></li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);">4</a></li>
```

And, to make matters much more tricky, I cannot use scripts. Just CSS.

Comment: No, you'd need JavaScript to do this reliably. There may be some hacky way to fake it using overflows, margins, and positioning, but it would be unreliable due to various font styles, two digit slide numbers, etc.

Comment: Thanks, @j08691. I was worried that was the case. But, if it is, we'll have to find an alternate solution!

Comment: as suggested by @j08691 JS would be the best option but if you have no choise and can tweak the CSS depending onf font, font-size... maybe this can help http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/wvwybz9e/

Comment: @web-tiki Thanks! That helped quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

One convoluted option could be to:

- use a custom font which only includes digits (all other chars being set to a 0-width space)
- apply that font to your link via CSS

Of course, that will look weird until the font is loaded or if the font fails to load.

As implied by j08691, if you have very tight control over the format (font, size..) you may be able to hack something with negative margins and `overflow: hidden`.